# Button not executing correct method in controller class

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .NET core and am creating my first small program. in the application I click a button and it should execute a method that performs an action. According to what I've found online it should be fairly simple to do this. Unfortunately I seemed to be missing something in my research. The button keeps calling the wrong method. There must be a setting some ware that I am missing. the way I understand it all I need to do is after asp-controller put the controller I want to use and after asp-action put the Method. Unfortunately it always calls the method called at startup.

```
<form method="post">
    <button asp-controller="Brochure" asp-action="Recall">Click Me</button>

</form>
```

Method called:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {        
        public ViewResult BrochureMain()
        {

        int ao = 0;
        int po = 0;

        using (var ctx = new BrochureDBContext())
        {
            var brochureSet = ctx.Brochure.FromSql  ($"usp_OAK_Brochure_Count")
                                            .ToList();
            foreach (var agencyOrder in brochureSet)
            {
                ao = agencyOrder.AgencyOrders;
                po = agencyOrder.PaxOrders;
            }
        }
        var model = new Brochure { AgencyOrders = ao, PaxOrders = po };
        return View(model);
    }
```

The method I want to call:

```
 public class BrochureController : Controller
{


    [HttpPost]

    public String Recall()
    {
        //Product product = repository.Products
        //.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        //if (product != null)
        //{
        //    cart.RemoveLine(product);
        //}
        return "Recall Test";
        //return View("ReloadOrders");
    }
```

Startup:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IMessageService, ConfigurationMessageService>();
        services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IMessageService msg)
    {           
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=BrochureMain}/{id?}");
        });
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {               
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(msg.GetMessage());
        });
    }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        if (env.IsDevelopment())

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `asp-controller`/`asp-action` attributes go on the *form*, not the button.

Comment: I'm not doubting you but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.0#the-form-action-tag-helper) seem to state differently (maybe I'm looking at the wrong docs?) Is this a .net core 3.0 feature only?

Comment: No, but that's the formaction tag helper. It serves to generate a `formaction` attribute, which *should* override the main action on the form, but it doesn't seem to be working for you for whatever reason. The only reason to use that, though, is if you need to have multiple submit buttons and route each to a different action, which is arguably not a great design in the first place. In your case, you just have the one, so it's more appropriate for the action to be on the form tag, and it's also more foolproof that way.

Comment: I'm not the OP, I was just trying to figure out their problem :) I wasn't even aware those tags could go on the button! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Chris I actually have several submit buttons on a form. I separated this one out so I could play with it and figure out how to get it to work. could you tell me why this is a poor design and what would be better? I'm trying to not write bad code so I would love to know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The asp-controller/asp-action attributes go on the form, and use button as submit type.

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Brochure" asp-action="Recall">
<button type="submit" >Click Me</button>
```

and for view response of recall action in browser, you should remove

```
 app.Run(async (context) =>
    {               
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(msg.GetMessage());
    });
```

from startup class.